assumptions of a glm
I am running a glm in R and from the residuals plots, the model doesnt meet the assumptions perfectly. My question is how well do these assumptions need to be met or is some deviation ok? I've tried transformations, adding interaction terms, removing outliers etc but nothing seems to improve it.
I am modelling yield in response to species proportions and also including dummy variables to account for special mixtures/treatment (controls)
glm(Annual_DM_Yield ~ 0 + Grass + Legume + I(Legume2) + I(Legume3) + Herb +
AV +
PRG_300N + PRG_150N + PRG_0N + PRGWC_0N + PRGWC_150N + N_Treatment_150N,
data=yield )
Any help greatly appreciated!


Are you specifying any family for the GLM, or are you essentially just fitting a linear model? The qq-plot look like it has mass concentrated in the lower yield, which advocates against the normal distribution - but the line looks fine, so I guess some inverse transformation is going on?

just essentially fitting a linear model, what do you mean by inverse transformation?

If you run "lm" instead of "glm", the qq plot will look like it is supposed to.

ahh, it looks like this now (https://imgur.com/wzRXM5r), there is still some deviations at the start and end of the tale in the qq plot and there does seem be a slight trend in the residual vs fitted plot

such is nature I guess. To me it looks fine, but I'm no expert on yields. Make sure you can interpret the model. The R-squared value can also be helpful in evaluating the information gain from covariates when having a linear regression model.

Instead of typing "glm" just type "lm" if you want to perform linear regression. GLM requires a family and link function. Leaving the argument empty assumes Gaussian family with identity link. Residuals have different interpretations in a GLM, and a great explaination is in the response here:
Where are the residuals in a GLM?
